# Why and how to use the @xml/file_paths resource in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

**tl;dr:** Why do I need a file_paths resource, when I retrieve a file_path dynamically during runtime?

I am currently learning Android Studio by building my own app.
What I want to do right now is to take a picture and then get some Text out of it.
To take a picture and use it lateron, I followed the [Taking Photos Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) guide of the Android Developers. At this point, it is suggested to use a [File Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles).

In the manifest, the File Provider is added like this:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

I am struggling with the `meta-data`, especially the `android:resource=@xml/file_paths"`

In the *Taking Photos Simply Tutorial*, this is the required addition to the XML to make it work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

So my question is: What is the good practise intended within the developer guide that I should follow, and how do I do that?

Edit: To make things clearer, I am having trouble understanding how to use a resource here at all.
This is the method code straigh out of the guide:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

So I am dynamically getting the name of the file (and therefore it's file path) during the Runtime of my application.
What is that file/paths for, I do not understand its usage.

Comment: instead of xml, try to put relevant path according to where you’ve out file-paths and if doesn’t help always try to run Clean Cashes and Restart in ADT

Comment: I think my understanding of resources is too little overall to find this solution helpful I do not think it is a Cashe-Problem, and more likely to being a problem of my lack of grapsing the resource-concept within this example.
Also, I have not declared any res/values/file-path   resource yet, if that helps

Comment: cleaning the cashes is just the button in Android Studio we click once we’ve got nithing working. Sometimes it just helps

Comment: where did you put your file? It’s path should be there instead of the xml in @xml

Comment: Well, in the createImageFile() Method the storage directory is determined like this: storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); 
So I do not know where I actually put the file

Comment: @.@ I need to sit on that deeply later on. Btw I meant where= what path

Comment: Yeah, this is where I am struggling: For my understanding, resource-values are fixed values, meaning they cannot be changed.
Still, I retrieve the storageDirectory during runtime, So I cannot know it's path before actually running the app. But exactly that is what the code solution by the android developer guide suggets here - so as you can tell I am super confused.

Comment: Uhm, I still do not understand what I need the resource for, but I found the problem: I put the <path> tags inside the manifest, but it actually belongs inside the res file.
Still, no idea why I need that

Comment: Wohoooo you found the problem! cheer up :) now regarding the other “problem” you have or misconception, describe me a little bit more briefully and I’ll try to understand and explain you whatever you need for full understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in the **res** directory and name it **xml**, create a file **file_paths** in it and replace everything with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

if you want to preview the captured image from that tutorial then decode the file from its path to bitmap and then display it onto a ImageView from the **onActivityResult()**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath)
        imageView?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically , it allows us to provide access to internal and external storage of the phone. by using  , we allow access to external storage and we can specify to allow full access to external storage or to a specific directory . The same goes for internal storage , we use  for accessing the internal storage .